# Dynamic form rendering using JSON schema

Tags: json, angular, ngx-formly

Can i store all UI elements in JSON and store it is Database.

These elements can be changed by admin based on user preference and tag aganist user in Database.

When user logs in he will his own UI.

How can i achieve this using framework and technology available

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can follow to render the dynamic HTML in angular.

- You can add the HTML Editor for some specific column.
- Add/Edit the html using the admin side.
- Save the HTML in the DB.
- Fetch the HTML on the front side and simply put this tag on html side.

> ```
> <div class="someclass" [innerHTML]="YourHtml">
>    </div>
> ```

Comment: your aproach is not an Angular aproach. you has no control over the elements in an innerHtml. e.g. you can not access to the variables or the submit button. Well, you can access using jQuery or another similar javascript but, for this, not use Angular. in the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form you has the aproach you need

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at angular's reactive forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms